# iCloud showing different sets of files to OS X users using same iCloud login

Tags: icloud, keynote, accounts

I have two accounts on my MAcbook Pro. One for work and one for home. I recently wanted to share a Keynote presentation between both accounts and the iPad. I logged both accounts into iCloud using the same iCloud account as well as the iPad.

But each account sees a different set of files. I don't understand why as they are both logged into the same iCloud account. I've also tried logging in via Safari and checked with Numbers and Pages as well. In all cases I could not get all files available to the applications.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually worked around this by turning of iCloud in both accounts, clearing the iCloud directories and then turning everything back on. Still no idea why it was happening in the first place.